# Trouble Connecting to Hidden Network with nmcli on First Attemp

Tags: bash, networkmanager, nmcli

I am using `nmcli` command to connect to a hidden network:

```
nmcli device wifi connect <hidden-network-ssid> password <password> hidden yes
```

When I use this command to connect to my network it never works on first try. It is not clear to me why must I enter the command more times subsequently to connect to that network.

Here is an example of that behaviour:
[image]

Is this expected behaviour and if so - is there a known workaround?